# Openshift ssh incorrect ruby version on bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

I have a Ruby 2.0 rails 4 app on openshift.

When I ssh into my application and run bundle install I get a message saying: 'Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0'.

When running `ruby -v`, I get :  "ruby 2.0.0p353..."

Running `gem environment` it also says Ruby 2.0.

Also on my local machine everything is working fine.

Why does my bundle install think I'm using ruby 1.8.7 on the openshift server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your bundler was installed before Ruby upgrade to 2. Try to install your bundler again using `gem install bundler` and then run `bundle install`

Let me know if it works

Comment: Wow. I can't believe that.  It was that simple.  Thanks! The amount of headaches you just saved me was large.  

Openshift hasn't updated their default bundler apparently.

Comment: Also just wanted to add for anyone who may use this in the future.  In addition to gem install bundler,  you might wat to declare your ruby version in the top of your Gemfile in order to be able to 'bundle install' from the ssh command line of your app.

Comment: Yup! I believe heroku guys used to say this to do in an upgrading-your-app stack documentation.